# IIS 8.0 Express and WebSocket on Windows 8 not working

Tags: c#, websocket, iis-express

I try to play around websockets and implemented Websocket server as IHttpHandler. I'm, working on Windows8, VisualStudio 2012 and IIS 8 express. Everytime when I try to connect to my server using javascript client I get context.IsWebSocketRequest equals false inside ProcessRequest method. When I switch to local IIS server everything works fine (context.IsWebSocketRequest is true) . Did I miss something? How can I force IIS Express to work with WebSockets?

My WebSocket server implementation:

```
public class WebSocketHandler: IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
       {
           context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessWebSocketRequest,new AspNetWebSocketOptions()
               {
                   RequireSameOrigin = true
               });
       }
    }

    private async Task ProcessWebSocketRequest(AspNetWebSocketContext socketContext)
    {
        var ws = socketContext.WebSocket;
        while (true)
        {
            //Do something...
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the WebSockets in the configuration?

http://www.paulbatum.com/2011/09/getting-started-with-websockets-in.html

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have installed that extension. As I mentioned before, when I switch to local IIS everything works fine. The problem is only when I try to run application using IIS express.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you answer very well at first. I thought you wrote about installed IIS modules (it looks similar). So, where can I find that configuration?

Comment: Follow the steps indicated in the link I provided.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't solve my problem. They don't use IIS Express (In one of the steps they untick 'Use IIS Express' option in project options)